# Attaching to running process via GDB causes lags

Tags: shell, gdc

When I attach to running process on my system (Ubuntu 12.04) I easily can make breakpoints, but when i hit the 'cont' command my system does nothing except printing "Continuing" message. I tried several commands always with the same result. What can causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

'cont' makes the program continue until a breakpoint is hit. Without further information, we can only assume the program does not hit any breakpoints.

Comment: Yes, not hitting breakpoints can be another interpretation of this problem. Thing is that I don't know what to add to my description because it happens without any errors or signals from system. I read about attaching in web and I'm pretty sure that I don't do any mistakes while doing that.

Comment: Sounds like you attach to the process fine. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: GDB doesn't hit any breakpoints, so I can't do anything to program that I'm attached to

Comment: You have to have some understanding of the program you are debugging. There is no way to know what you are trying to achieve with debugging of the program. Typically, you'd set a bp that gets hit, like breaking on main and step through the program or you've read the code, and know a specific function you want to break in and then exercise that code path via typical program interaction. You have not provide enough information as far as I can tell to help. The 'lag' you refer to is just the program running. Debugged program do often run slower though, so lag here is misleading.